# Как получить путь к элементу массива Integer?

Tags: android

Добрый день. Мой вопрос возможно глупый, но я никак не могу разобраться с ним. Мне требуется сделать декодинг изображения:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile( /* PATH TO PIC */, options);
```

Но мои изображения хранятся в массиве(drawable):

```
 public Integer[] myPics = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5,
            R.drawable.pic6, R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8,
            R.drawable.pic9, R.drawable.pic10, R.drawable.pic11,
            R.drawable.pic12, R.drawable.pic13, R.drawable.pic14,
            R.drawable.pic15, R.drawable.pic16, R.drawable.pic17,
            R.drawable.pic18, R.drawable.pic19, R.drawable.pic20,
            R.drawable.pic21 };
```

метод decodeFile первым параметром получает только стринговый путь. Я пробовал доставать элемент из массива по позиции или номер элемента, но это всё не подходит.
Собственно сабж

***UPD** пробовал через декод ресурсов, но он тоже не хочет чет работать `decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), mThumbIds[path], options);`

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно получить путь к файлу из сгенерированного при компиляции уникального `ID`, коим и являются константы класса R, наполняющие ваш массив.

Возможно, вам надо переделать метод так, чтобы он принимал объект типа `Bitmap`

Comment: Понятно, будем думать. Но тут вытекает сразу второй вопрос, я вывожу изображения в GridView, их всего 20 шт.. Без декодировки они выводятся, но ужасно медленно листаются как на эмуляторе Genymotion, так и на реальном устройстве. После удачной декодировки ситуация изменится или тут дело в чём-то другом?

Comment: @Denis422, возможно они у вас большого размера слишком. Попробуйте их спец. либой отображать а не самостоятельно. Например Picasso, Glide

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась использованием стандартного гугловского решения по декодингу изображений [тык](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

```
  imageView.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mContext.getResources(),mThumbIds[position], 100, 100));
```